# Filter rows after applying MAX function on dataframe in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to know how can we apply the filter function after applying MAX function on data frame using Pyspark.

Example: Display the name of the employee who earns the highest salary.

In sql,

```sql
select ename from emp where sal=(select max(sal) from emp) ;
```

I want to apply same logic on dataframe in Pyspark.

Answer (score 0):

same query should work (tried in spark=2.4.5)

```scala
val df = Seq(("emp1", 100), ("emp2", 200)).toDF("ename", "sal")
    df.createOrReplaceTempView("emp")

    spark.sql(
      """
        | select ename from emp where sal=(select max(sal) from emp)
      """.stripMargin)
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +-----+
      * |ename|
      * +-----+
      * |emp2 |
      * +-----+
      */
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val sourceDF = Seq( (1, 10,  "05-10-2019"),
    (2, 20,  "07-22-2020"),
    (3, 30,  "11-03-2017"))
    .toDF("id", "metric", "transaction_date")

  sourceDF.show(false)
//  +---+------+----------------+
//  |id |metric|transaction_date|
//  +---+------+----------------+
//  |1  |10    |05-10-2019      |
//  |2  |20    |07-22-2020      |
//  |3  |30    |11-03-2017      |
//  +---+------+----------------+

  val resDF = sourceDF.filter('metric.equalTo(sourceDF.agg(max('metric)).head().getInt(0)))

  resDF.show(false)
//  +---+------+----------------+
//  |id |metric|transaction_date|
//  +---+------+----------------+
//  |3  |30    |11-03-2017      |
//  +---+------+----------------+
```

Comment: I am trying in Pyspark and above suggested query is giving syntax issues like: SyntaxError: invalid syntax.

Initially I tried the following syntax: 
emp.withColumn('sal',emp.sal.cast('double')).agg({'sal':'max'}).withColumnRenamed('MAX(sal)','max_sal').where((emp.sal.cast('double')) == 'max_sal').show().

It's thwoing an error: pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: 'Resolved attribute(s) sal#15 missing from max_sal#62 in operator !Filter (cast(sal#15 as double) = cast(max_sal as double)).

Comment: @user3699972 - please try df.agg({"age": "max"}).collect().... - you need  receive only value. now return  [Row(max(age)=5)]

Comment: @user3699972 - pyspark: df.agg(max(df.A)).head()[0] - like in scala (my answer)

Comment: tmp = emp.withColumn('sal',emp.sal.cast('double')).agg({'sal':'max'}).withColumnRenamed('MAX(sal)','max_sal').collect()
    emp.where(emp.sal.isin(tmp)).show().

Comment: It's giving an error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class java.util.ArrayList [5000.0]

Comment: Can you help me here

Comment: @user3699972 - please, give example your data. and I try.